# Simple console application calculator functions

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, while-loop

I've tested a simple calculator functions as a part of my C# studies and I have a problem, it won't exit the while loop even if I type the right choise.
Here is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string calc, inputX, inputY, inputZ;
        double x, y, z;

        Console.Write("Welcome to the cool calculator. Please choose between sumCalc or multiCalc: ");
        calc = Console.ReadLine();

        while (calc != "sumCalc" || calc != "sumCalc")
        {
            Console.Write("Please type in the right calculator again: ");
            calc = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        if (calc == "sumCalc")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are now working with the sumCalc.");
            //Getting user input for the variable 'x'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the first number:");
            inputX = Console.ReadLine();
            x = Convert.ToDouble(inputX);
            //Getting user input for the variable 'y'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the second number:");
            inputY = Console.ReadLine();
            y = Convert.ToDouble(inputY);
            //Getting user input for the variable 'z'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the third number:");
            inputZ = Console.ReadLine();
            z = Convert.ToDouble(inputZ);
            Console.WriteLine("The result is:" + sumCalc(x, y, z));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else if (calc == "multiCalc")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You are now working with the multiCalc.");
            //Getting user input for the variable 'x'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the first number:");
            inputX = Console.ReadLine();
            x = Convert.ToDouble(inputX);
            //Getting user input for the variable 'y'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the second number:");
            inputY = Console.ReadLine();
            y = Convert.ToDouble(inputY);
            //Getting user input for the variable 'z'
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value for the third number:");
            inputZ = Console.ReadLine();
            z = Convert.ToDouble(inputZ);
            Console.WriteLine("The result is:" + multiCalc(x, y, z));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    //This is the multiply calculator function
    static double sumCalc(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double res = x + y + z;
        return res;
    }

    //This is the multiply calculator function
    static double multiCalc(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        double res = x * y * z;
        return res;
    }
```

I don't know why it does that, it should work just fine.
Please help me, thanks! :)

Comment: Next time such type of question will get closed. `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behaviour, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Comment: Got it, won't happen next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You have `sumCalc` twice in `while` condition. Also change `||` to `&&`, if you use `OR` as the condition, even if you enter `sumCalc` OR `multiCalc`, the loop will be true and keep asking you to enter again.

```
while (calc != "sumCalc" && calc != "multiCalc")
```

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, I typed it instead of multiCalc :P

Comment: @Reniuz if you use OR, it will be endless because loop will always be true, i did test this before posting the answer.

Comment: @Reniuz think about the logic of OR, 0 || 1 = 1 but AND is 0 && 1 = 0. I had to revise my memory of this also to be honest.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, you are correct. I am terrible at translating :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code :

```
while (calc != "sumCalc" && calc != "multiCalc")
```

instead of :

```
while (calc != "sumCalc" || calc != "sumCalc")
```